# VS Code Live Server Not Refreshing automatically

Tags: html, css, vscode-extensions, liveserver

So the issue is I have installed VS Code along with Live Server for HTML CSS. Normally the page should reload on its own after i edit in my HTML but no victory.

I have turned on Auto-Save but still, Live Server is not auto updating/Refreshing my page. I have to reload every single time to see the changes. Need Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure your both VS code and live server extension are updated to latest version.

Secondly if everything is good, then in your HTML file right click and select open with live server option.

Or else there will be button at the bottom right written as live server. Click on that.

Also, try changing the browser if this cant solve.

And also once close the vs code once and restart it again.